# Site can't be reached

Tags: docker, nginx

I am using `jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine` image to create a container.Here is the link [nginx-proxy](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/).

`docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock.ro --name nginx \ jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine`

I have successfully created the container which is running up.
Then, I start my container to be proxied with the environment variable as

```
  docker run \
    -d \
    --entrypoint /docker-entrypoint.sh \
    -e VIRTUAL_HOST=xyz.mydomain.info \ //running app on xyz.mydomain.info,but 
    not working.
    -e VIRTUAL_PORT=8000 //what does it mean?
    --name server \
    image_name
```

The container named as `server` is up and running.

**Question1**: Do I need to open any port in the ec2 security groups in order to 
               run the application?

**Question2**: I can see the application running on `xyz.mydomain.info`.

**Question3**: What is the use of virtual_port here? In my Dockerfile the container's `EXPOSE` on port 8000.

Answer (score 1):

**Question1: Do I need to open any port in the ec2 security groups in order to run the application?**

Only 80 or 443, depending on which one you are using. Rest all would work internally on the machine

**Question2: I can see the application running on xyz.mydomain.info**

By either pointing a DNS entry of that domain to your server, or by creating a host entry in your OS hosts file (for testing purpose)

**Question3: What is the use of virtual_port here? In my Dockerfile the container's EXPOSE on port 8000.**

`nginx-proxy` needs to understand which port it should be proxy passing to your traffic inside the container. By default it takes the exposed port. If there are multiple you can specify which one using `VIRTUAL_PORT`